# How to get JSON data without special tags?

Tags: json

I am using API to get data from the site.
I got those data like next:

1>

```
  "tags": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "action:archived"
      },
      {
        "name": "archived"
      },
      {
        "name": "inbox"
      },
      {
        "name": "source:email"
      }
    ]
  }
```

2>

```
  "tags": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "inbox"
      },
      {
        "name": "source:email"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And follow the manual, I could get the data only with tag "inbox" not the "archived" using the link like this: `https://abc.com/DATA?tags=inbox`, I tried and as you could guess, both data have the tag named "inbox", if I want to get the data without the tag "`archived`", what could I do?

Thank you for your time and any hint would be helpful.

Comment: I haven't got the foggiest idea what you're trying to do or what your question is.  If you want data of a particular nature you need to talk to the folks at the other end of that URL.

Comment: Thank you Hot Licks, I want to know could I use link like this :https://abc.com/DATA?tags!=archived

Comment: You can't just use `!=` like that.  The `tags=inbox` is saying that the parameter "tags" has the value "inbox".  Like I said, you'd need to talk to the folks at the other end to see what other options might be available -- there's nothing standard about URL parameter meanings from one site to the next.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to try many methods before I could ask because it's my big client's API. Any way, I know I could not use "!=" ,Thank you.

Comment: The folks at the other end should supply you with the specifications for their protocol -- it's their job.